# Formula for all terms in a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking to find an algorithm for a repeating pattern, in order to solve a programming problem. I need a formula for all terms of the following sequence:

```
0, 2, 4, ..., 0, 2, 4, ...
```

The sequence would start at 0, and then increment by 2 until reaching 4 and then repeat itself with 0. I have worked with similar patterns, and they usually involve the modulus operator, and the number of repeating terms. For example, from what I understand I could get a repeating pattern just by applying the modulo to the index by the number of repeating terms.

This seems like it should be simple enough, but is eluding me and I do not have a mathematics background.

Comment: Do you mean something like $a_n=\begin{cases} 0,&n\equiv 0\mod 3 \\ 2,&n\equiv 1\mod 3\\4,&n\equiv 2\mod 3\end{cases},~n\geq 0$?

Comment: @Hirshy Yes, where n could go to any number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply say that the $i$-th element of the sequence is the remainder of when you divide $2\cdot i$ by $6$.

That is, if you count $0$ as the zero-th element. If it's the first, just replace the $i$ with $(i-1)$.

---

For example:

- $0$ is the remainder when you divide $2\cdot 0$ by $6$
- $2$ is the remainder when you divide $2\cdot 1$ by $6$
- $4$ is the remainder when you divide $2\cdot 2$ by $6$
- $0$ is the remainder when you divide $2\cdot 3$ by $6$
- $2$ is the remainder when you divide $2\cdot 4$ by $6$
- $4$ is the remainder when you divide $2\cdot 5$ by $6$

So, if you want to calculate the $i$-th element in, say, Python, you would calculate it as

```
i_th_element = (2 * i) % 6
```

Comment: Okay, this will take me a minute to understand. Let me try it on a few indices. Yeah I don't really care if it starts with 6, because like I said I am just applying it to a programming problem.

Comment: Yeah see this isn't going to work for me, I need it to repeat.

Comment: @StevieV It *does* repeat...

Comment: Okay, you had a typo.

Comment: @StevieV Yes. But you can easily check it repeats yourself. It's a simple formula. It shouldnt take you more than $10$ seconds to calculate...

Comment: I stated in the question I do not have a math background. Thanks.

Comment: @StevieV Well, you don't need a math background to answer the question "what is the remainder of $2\cdot 5$ when you divide it by $6$"... Anyone over 10 years of age should be able to answer that :)

Comment: You are talking about doing that? Yeah I could've thought about it a little harder, but I thought you were saying I should be able to figure out this whole thing in 10s :)

Comment: @StevieV Nah, that takes more practice :). Although I would say that it's fairly basic math, and if you want to be a good programmer, you need much more than just basic math -- keep practicing until a task like this becomes trivial and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Something like $a_n = 2(n \text{ mod } 3)$ starting at $a_0 = 0$ ?